# Why does my summation program behaves weird?

Tags: c, for-loop, variables, while-loop, scope

Yesterday, I had to do a math introduction test, where I had to calculate the cardinality of a summation. I was lazy to write it out and I thought I'd just write a small C program to solve it. I felt confident that'll work, since I did much more complex programs, but I just can't get it to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int i = 1;  
    int n = 2 * i + 1;

    while(n <= 36){
        printf("%d\n", n);
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In theory, there should have been the sequence "3, 5, 7, 9, ...", but all I get is "3, 3, 3, 3, ...". It's only not working if I'm using the variable `n`, if I replace it with `i` within `while` everything works as I would expect.

What am I missing?

Comment: Because your expectation is weird.  You've done more complex programs in which language?  You will not have written much in C of any complexity with this apparent misunderstanding of how the language works.  I cannot see how replacing `n` with `i` would produce the output `3, 5, 7, 9, ...`; surely it produces `1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 36`?  If you have tried alternative code you should include that code rather then "describe" it.

Comment: Seems I forgot to write I'm a beginner by all means. With "complex" I mean, that I wrote different small C programs (and somewhat also in javascript and python) that were longer and more complex. PS: Thanks for formatting, but reason as to why you changed "behaves weird" to "behavesweird"?

Comment: I did not touch the formatting, and don't recall touching the title but I am logged against that edit.  Restored, but it is nonetheless a bad title; it is not behaving weird at all.  Neither Python nor Javascript behave in the manner you seem to expect here either.

Comment: I think I started to fix the title and got distracted, leaving it 'vandalised'

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
int n = 2 * i + 1;
```

Is not a formula for `n` which gets calculated every time `n` is used.  It sets `n` to the value of `2 * i + 1 == 2 * 1 + 1 == 2 + 1 == 3` at the time the statement is encountered and that's it.  So `n` never changes inside of the loop and you end up with an infinite loop.

Move the assignment to inside the loop:

```
while(n <= 36){
    printf("%d\n", n);
    i++;
    n = 2 * i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no change of value `n` in the `while` loop and so it never fail the condition `n <= 36`. Maybe you want to do this way

```
while(n <= 36){
    printf("%d\n", n);
    i++;
    n = 2 * i + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It always gives `3` as a result because you do not update `n` at each iteration. `n` is calculated once at the beginning. You should calculate `n` again each time `i` is incremented.